# Can we reduce the number of operations for this case?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, numerical-methods

Suppose we want to compute $(A-B)c$ with smallest number of operations where $A=2x$, $B=y+b^{*}$, $b^{*}=y-z$ and we are given $c, x, y, z, b^{*}$ that are non-negative.

From above $A,B$ are double precision and the givens are single precision numbers. Therefore, computing $2x$ directly makes it double and similarly, adding $y$ to $b^{*}$ straightaway makes it double too. Here we are ignoring the storage requirement for the sign of a number. One of the methods is given below

1) First compute $t=(x-b^{*})-z$ then $tc$ and $2tc$. Also compute $zc$ and finally $2tc+zc=(A-B)c$. This method takes $2$ multiplications and $2$ subtractions of single precision. $1$ multiplication by 2 of double precision and $1$ addition of double precision.

Is it possible to reduce the number of operations further?

Comment: Why such strange names for the various quantities? It would be easier to grasp "compute $(2x-(y+(y-z)))w$, given $x$, $y$, $z$ and $y-z$ (but not $w$?)", writing $x$ for $a_i$, $y$ for$b_j$, $z$ for $b_l$ and $w$ for $C$. What prevents you from multiplying $x$ by $2$? What prevents you from adding $y$ to $y-z$? And how does your distinction between operations of "single precision" and "double precision" work?

Comment: @HenningMakholm I have changed the name of quantities. Multiplying $x$ by $2$ will cause problem in case of single precision operation. Similarly addition of $y$ to $b^{*}$ also causes problem in single precision addition. By single precision I mean the the quantities are of a particular length/size. So when we multiply them the length/size increases. That's why multiplying $x$ by $2$ will increase the length/size which is not a problem once we get into double precision.

Comment: (1) You need to supply the rules you use for distinguishing single and double precision operations in the question. Currently there seems to be no way a reader can predict which width you will consider which operations to have. (2) Does the star on $b^*$ mean anything to you that you want the reader to take into account, or is it just there for continued obfuscation of your problem? If it means something relevant to the problem **you need to explain what** rather than leave the reader to guess.

Comment: Anyway, it is **impossible** to compute the expression using the four givens you have specified, because none of the givens allow you to know anything about the value of $C$.

Comment: @HenningMakholm thanks and I will modify the question to make it more clear.

Comment: @HenningMakholm I hope things are much clear and obvious now. By the way about $b^{*}$ it is just a value given to us.